# Compile error with non-constant array declaration, C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

Weird, very weird case.
Consider the code:

```
int n = 50;
auto p1 = new double[n][5]; //OK
auto p2 = new double[5][n]; //Error
```

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:17:26: error: array size in new-expression must be constant
> auto p2 = new double[5][n]; //Error
>
> main.cpp:17:26: error: the value of ‘n’ is not usable in a constant expression
> main.cpp:15:8: note: ‘int n’ is not const

Can anyone explain why do I get a compile error on the second one but the first one works perfectly?

Comment: "gets a compile error", doesn't post the error.

Comment: It might help you to see [how the compiler parses those lines](https://godbolt.org/g/y5eyXP).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `new double[n][5]` you are allocating `n` values of type `double[5]`.

With `new double[5][n]` you are allocating `5` [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). And C++ doesn't have VLA's so that's invalid.

The solution, as ever, is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> p2(5, std::vector<double>(n));
```

The above defines `p2` to be a vector of vectors of `double`. It constructs `p2` to have a size of `5` elements, where each element is initialized to a vector of `n` values.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is explained, incidentially with the *exact* example that you give (funny!?) on the `new[]` expression page on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) under the section "Explanation". See excerpt:

> If type is an array type, all dimensions other than the first must be specified as positive integral constant expression (until C++14) converted constant expression of type std::size_t (since C++14), but the first dimension may be any expression convertible to std::size_t. This is the only way to directly create an array with size defined at runtime, such arrays are often referred to as dynamic arrays.